# Quick estimate of attractor of non-linear dynamical system

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ds.dynamical-systems

Say I have a system of form 
$$
\frac{dy}{dt} = f(y),
$$

and it is know this system has an attractor. Can I quickly for given $\varepsilon$ guess some point, such in its $\varepsilon$- neighbourhood will be present at least one point of this attractor? Quicker that integrating system itself?

Comment: The attractor of a system is a very transcendental object. I doubt very much you can obtain an approximation without solving (say, numerically) said system itself.

Comment: @LoïcTeyssier Is there any symptoms if numerical  solution (or any other approximation) is nearing attractor?

Comment: I saw a talk once (can't recall the author, sorry) in which the phase space was discretised, leading to successive refinement of the Lorenz attractor.  It is still solving the dynamics, of course, but using an approximation of the transfer operator rather than the original ODE.  Not sure if this is quicker, also will lead to different sets if there is non-transitive behaviour.  I took the liberty of suggesting the "dynamical systems" tag.

Comment: @Moonwalker: not as far as I know...

Comment: I believe Carl is mentioning the works of Dellnitz,Junge. See "On the Approximation of Complicated Dynamical Behavior" SIAM J. Numer. Anal., 36(2) 1999

Comment: Also relevant, a recent paper: "ESTIMATING LONG-TERM BEHAVIOR OF FLOWS WITHOUT TRAJECTORY INTEGRATION: THE INFINITESIMAL GENERATOR APPROACH", SIAM J. NUMER. ANAL, 2014.

Comment: @Piyush - thanks, I think you're right.  Probably closer to 2014 than 1999.